# is there a closed form expression for the following matrix infinite series

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider this infinite sum of matrices. Is there any closed form to express this sum?

$S=B+ABA^T +A^2B({A^T})^2+A^3B({A^T})^3+...$

And B is diagonal. 
Thanks

Comment: Why are you asking this (in what context did you encounter this sum)? The notation is also a bit strange. Normally $T$ is used to denote the transpose. Is $A^{T^2} = (A^T)^T$ or $(A^T)^2$ or is $T$ a real number?

Comment: Note that $ASA^T-S=B$

Comment: Sorry about the notation, yes T denotes transpose. I mean $(A^T)^2$.

Comment: @Winther that's the only notation that I've seen for transpose, unless you insist on using $\top$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the series expansion for the discrete time Lyapunov matrix equation
\begin{equation}
ASA^T - S = B
\end{equation}
mentioned by Hagen von Eitzen. It is central in the model reduction of discrete time dynamical systems. Here B is frequently a matrix of very low rank. The series is convergent if, say, the spectral norm of $A$ is strictly less than $1$. In practice, we distinguish between two cases: either $A$ is small and dense or it is large and sparse. If $A$ is dense, then we use two sided orthogonal transformations $U$ to reduce $A$ to (quasi) upper triangular form $A = UTU^T$. The transformed equation
\begin{equation}
T Y T^T - Y = U^T B U
\end{equation}
can then be solved recursively for the columns of $Y = U^T S U$. Back transformation completes the job. If $A$ is large and sparse and $B$ is low rank, then an iterative method is used, typically a Krylov subspace method or a variant of the low rank alternating direction implicit method.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that the infinite sum converges.  Then, as noted in the comments, we must have
$$
ASA^T - S = B
$$
This is a linear equation on $S$ that we can solve.  In particular, let $\operatorname{vec}$ denote the [vectorization operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_%28mathematics%29). We then have
$$
(A \otimes A - I) \operatorname{vec}(S) = \operatorname{vec}(B)
$$
where $\otimes$ denotes the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product).  Assuming invertibility, we can write
$$
\operatorname{vec}(S) = (A \otimes A - I)^{-1} \operatorname{vec}(B)
$$
A sufficient condition for both the invertibility of $A$ and the convergence of the series is that $\rho(A) < 1$ (where $\rho$ denotes the spectral radius).