# Closed form of $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} X^k M (X^\top)^k$

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, matrices, matrix-calculus

Let $X,M\in M_n(\mathbb R)$ and additionally suppose that $X$ is a convergent matrix, that is to say its spectral radius $\rho(X)$ is strictly less than $1$. Define matrix $C$ to be

$$C=\sum_{k=1}^\infty X^k M (X^\top)^k.$$

> Is there a closed analytic form for matrix $C$ in terms of matrices
>   $X$ and $M$ and possibly some constant matrices? If not in general, how about for special cases such as $M=I$?

I did not get very far on my own. Let $D=M+C$, now $X D X^\top=D-M$. If one could solve for $D$ one would find $C$ as well, but I don't know how to do that. By the way, I think $C$ should exist whenever $X$ is convergent, is this correct?

Comment: I think that you will find [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1646424/81360) helpful

Comment: What is the definition of a "convergent matrix" in this context?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thanks for the link. By convergent matrix I mean a matrix with a spectral radius less than unity, I added this to the question.

Comment: great.  Is there anything from the other question that you would like clarified, or could I close this question as a duplicate?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Can you please verify that the posted answers to that question do not require that $M$ must be diagonal? If this is the case then I have the answer I was looking for there and this question can be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Indeed, neither of the answers actually make use of (or even refer to) the fact that $B$ is diagonal.